# Export Animation From Blender To Lumberyard Or Unity For Rendering

Tags: animation, export, unity

I would like to export my full animation to lumberyard or unity for rendering. The rendering in these programs seems to be realistic and fast enough for my animation. As far as I have managed to learn, there is no official support for exporting animations from blender to lumberyard, so if someone can help me and many others that would be great.